# HTML How to display all user input on single line with space inbetween each

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, output

I want to display all of the user input from  and  unto a single line (with space between each) when I press a button.
I already have the button working and it does display the user input, but not in the way I want it to.

How it displays:

```
one
two
three
```

How I want it to display:

```
one two three
```

All I find is how to display python, which I'm not even using. How should my code look like? (Btw, I'm not an expert at JavaScript or anything harder than that; got the JS from somewhere else)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href=""  />

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#">

        <h1>Cert Form</h1>

        <div>
            <label for="typeOfCSR">Choose the type of...</label>
            <select name="typeOfCSR" id="typeOfCSR">
                <option value="">Select an Option </option>
                <option value="One">One</option>
                <option value="Two">Two</option>
                <option value="Three">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="CN"> Enter the CN...</label>
            <textarea cols="100" rows="1" id="CN"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="FQDN"> Enter the FQDN...</label>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="FQDN"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="alternateName"> Enter the alt name</label>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="altName"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="nameOfCert"> Enter the name...</label>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="nameOfCert"></textarea>
        </div>

        </div>

        <button type="button" id="review">Generate String</button>
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>
    <br/>

    <div id="result" style="border: 3px solid black;"> Result will show here</div>

    <script>
        const btn = document.getElementById('review');
        btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            let typeOfCSR = document.getElementById('typeOfCSR').value;
            let CN = document.getElementById('CN').value;
            let FQDN = document.getElementById('FQDN').value;
            let altName = document.getElementById('altName').value;
            let nameOfCert = document.getElementById('nameOfCert').value;

            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  typeOfCSR +"<br/>"+ CN +"<br/>"+ FQDN +"<br/>"+ altName +"<br/>"+ nameOfCert;
        })


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `<br/>` between each entry, which makes them show on separate lines, replace it with a space. And you should never use `innerHTML` when dealing with user's input, use `textContent` instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href=""  />

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#">

        <h1>Cert Form</h1>

        <div>
            <label for="typeOfCSR">Choose the type of...</label>
            <select name="typeOfCSR" id="typeOfCSR">
                <option value="">Select an Option </option>
                <option value="One">One</option>
                <option value="Two">Two</option>
                <option value="Three">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="CN"> Enter the CN...</label>
            <textarea cols="100" rows="1" id="CN"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="FQDN"> Enter the FQDN...</label>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="FQDN"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="alternateName"> Enter the alt name</label>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="altName"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="nameOfCert"> Enter the name...</label>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="nameOfCert"></textarea>
        </div>

        </div>

        <button type="button" id="review">Generate String</button>
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>
    <br/>

    <div id="result" style="border: 3px solid black;"> Result will show here</div>

    <script>
        const btn = document.getElementById('review');
        btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            let typeOfCSR = document.getElementById('typeOfCSR').value;
            let CN = document.getElementById('CN').value;
            let FQDN = document.getElementById('FQDN').value;
            let altName = document.getElementById('altName').value;
            let nameOfCert = document.getElementById('nameOfCert').value;

            document.getElementById('result').textContent =  typeOfCSR +" "+ CN +" "+ FQDN +" "+ altName +" "+ nameOfCert;
        })


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```